# Building a c project with an option of using assert()

Tags: c

I need to use the function `assert()` only for a particular build of my C project.

Meaning thereby, there will be two builds of the same project; one with `assert()` operation and another without. Now, a way is to have a project with `assert()` function wherever it's required and one with none. But, is there any way so that I can have a single project with an option of enabling or disabling the usability of `assert()` function?

Comment: `assert` is a macro, and it can be disabled by defining `NDEBUG`. Typically you'd pass `-DNDEBUG` to your compiler. What compiler and build system are you using?

Comment: I am using IAR EWARM. So, we can't pass it as a compiler option via console or terminal. So, can it be done by placing  #define NDEBUG in some header file? If so, which header file would you recommend. And, by doing so will I land up in some problem?

Comment: @Anand you would have to `#define NDEBUG` before every standard header `#include` in every file.

Comment: @Anand: Often projects define a top-level header file (sometimes `config.h`) that is included by all of the sources in the project.  That would be a good place to define NDEBUG or leave it undefined.  Of course that means that anytime you modify the top-level header, everything has to be recompiled.

Comment: So, did you read the man-page of `assert`? What did you not understand? From the POSIX man-page: "Forcing a definition of the name NDEBUG, either from the compiler command line or with the preprocessor control statement #define NDEBUG ahead of the #include <assert.h> statement, shall stop assertions from being compiled into the program."

Comment: Yes I went through. If the NDEBUG is defined it implies ((void)0)

Comment: In an embedded context, it's common to turn assertions into some error handling that ends with a `while(1)` so that your watchdog can restart you or you can get an error trace if you connect your JTAG. Handling of run-time errors can be tricky business on devices that are left to run on their own. IMO you should only assert() conditions that makes execution impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Under MSVC, assert operates only for a debug build, i.e. when the _DEBUG preprocessor symbol is defined instead of NDEBUG.

You can very well define you own ASSERT(x) symbol as assert(x) or nothing depending on the build.

Comment: I want to use the same in production environment too

Comment: You can "steal" the definition of assert. Under MSVC: `#define assert(_Expression) (void)( (!!(_Expression)) || (_wassert(_CRT_WIDE(#_Expression), _CRT_WIDE(__FILE__), __LINE__), 0) )`

Comment: Once more MSVC is not standard compliant. I don't see the question is MSVC related, though. Using some MSVC code is probably not a good idea considering its incompatibility.

Comment: @Olaf: in what way is it non-compliant ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: In terms of using `_DEBUG` instead of `NDEBUG`, see the standard, 7.2p1. (The implementation is also non-portable, but that is normal. It just should not use as a reference.)

Comment: @olaf: my bad, NDEBUG disables assertions. So their assert macro is portable.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: I strongly doubt `_CRT_WIDE` etc. are standard. And supporting `NDEBUG` is mandatory, so the change to `_DEBUG` makes it non-compliant (note: i judge from your text only - mabe you are imprecise here?). Also according to the standard, this is not necessarily for debug builds (they don't exist in the standard) only.

Comment: @Olaf: these belong to the implementation, which is not visible to the user. This doesn't impair portability, the assert macro has the right semantics.

Comment: @Olaf you're probably referring to the C11 standard, but I seriously doubt MSVC is compliant to something more then an intersection between C89 and whatever they use nowadays for C++.

Comment: Of course I do. There is no other valid C standard. But `NDEBUG` is much older actually. Yes, I know that. That's the reson MSVC is a bad catch to compile C programs. It is one major reason C programmers don't adopt modern C.